# Azure Sql Database Read Only

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I ran into a issue where I used all my credited funds for my BizSpark account. Thus my database went into read only.  I removed my spending limit and attached a valid credit card. Saved my changes, however my database is still read only.  How can I set it to write and read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DB is read-only most probably because you reached the Size Limit for the SKU. You can either (delete some records) or update the SKU.

Read more about [Azure SQL Database SKUs here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/). And for [Size here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336245.aspx):

> If the size of the database reaches its MAXSIZE, you will receive an
>   error code 40544. When this occurs, you cannot insert or update data,
>   or create new objects, such as tables, stored procedures, views, and
>   functions. However, you can still read and delete data, truncate
>   tables, drop tables and indexes, and rebuild indexes. If you remove
>   some data to free storage space, there can be as much as a
>   fifteen-minute delay before you can insert new data.

Comment: My database is readonly because I used all my funds. Not because of size issues.

Comment: this shall be changed when you remove the CAP. try changing the SKU back and forth to see if this will change something.

Answer (score 1):

Once I was notified that my account reached it's cap and my database became read-only, I removed the cap. However, removing the cap does not instantly allow the database to become read only.  So my impatience suggested that there was more to do after removing the cap.  However, once you remove the cap, you just have to wait a few hours before the database goes back to read write.